# Как работает Руби

Tags: ruby, книги

Здравствуйте.
Начал знакомиться с руби и возник такой вопрос: ( сабж )

Как работает руби?

Есть ли статьи, где можно почитать, как вообще реализована интерпретация?
Как парсится код? И вообще что происходит, когда запускаешь на исполнение файл, код, программу?

Comment: "интерпрЕтация", "парсиТСЯ", запятые. Изучите сначала русский язык.

Comment: @pirj я бы не сказал, что слово "интерпретация" такое уж русское, ну а слово "парсить" вообще в русском языке отсутствует. С другой стороны, да, ошибки детские

Comment: Вообще-то, единственным достоверным описанием программы является ее исходный код.

Comment: Запомните отличие от других языков - в руби код выполняется сверху вниз построчно. И в процессе этого выполнения объявляются классы/методы и т.д.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Читайте про [лексический](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7) и [синтаксический](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7) анализ. Классическим трудом на тему построения компиляторов является "Книга дракона", но она сложновата для понимания и требует некоторого математического базиса. Могу посоветовать главы [24](http://lord-n.narod.ru/download/books/walla/programming/Spr_po_C/24/24.htm) и [29](http://lord-n.narod.ru/download/books/walla/programming/Spr_po_C/29/29.htm) книги Г. Шилдта "[Полный справочник по C](http://lord-n.narod.ru/download/books/walla/programming/Spr_po_C/main.htm)", в них объясняются принципы разбора выражений и пишется простенький интерпретатор подмножества C. Описанные там принципы можно применить и к другим языкам программирования, в том числе и к Ruby.